# Is there a way to train my Machine Learning model to fit 8 images into circle?

Tags: machine-learning

I simply have circle and 8 png images. Is there a way to train my model to have possibility to receive an output image with 8 images filled as much as possible into that circle?

This is an example output prepared in photoshop:

[image]

But I need to have a model, which will let me use it in Xcode with Swift. Then I run that model with any 8 images, and the result will be an output image filled with these 8 images as much as possible.

- size of images, rotation, position is randomly generated
- ratio is preserved
- parameters for every image should be returned for that model (I need to be able to recreate it manually from code, so I need x, y, rotation, scale for every image in circle)

Any ideas? Is it possible to train that model [here](https://aws.amazon.com/free/machine-learning/?trk=ps_a131L0000057lrEQAQ&trkCampaign=acq_paid_search&sc_channel=ps&sc_campaign=acquisition_pl&sc_publisher=google&sc_category=Machine%20Learning&sc_country=PL&sc_geo=EMEA&sc_outcome=acq&sc_detail=%2Bmachine%20%2Blearning&sc_content=machine_learning_bmm&sc_segment=383566122950&sc_medium=ACQ-P%7CPS-GO%7CNon-Brand%7CDesktop%7CSU%7CMachine%20Learning%7CSolution%7CPL%7CEN%7CText&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!383566122950!b!!g!!%2Bmachine%20%2Blearning&ef_id=CjwKCAiAsNKQBhAPEiwAB-I5zamG_IPXNUslypwZ0FRKZ673LigpRlvgSc_RJar-gFQQ4--KyZBZoxoCgoEQAvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!383566122950!b!!g!!%2Bmachine%20%2Blearning) for example? Or in any other place? Do you know any website where I can ask for help? Of course not for free.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't actually want random sizes and rotations, but rather something that optimizes them so that the circle is "almost filled." Is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly… you are right.

Comment: I dont think this is a machine learning problem. You can possibly frame this as some sort of optimization problem with different translations/rotations/resizing of each image. A simple algorithm is to do a greedy approach placing one item at a time rotating/resizing/translating until it fits. You can do backtracking if it still doesnt work,